# Hibernate Id Sequence Resulting null in Entity having two columns with sequence

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

1. I have one Table in postgresql database with two id Sequence.

```
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false,unique=true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY,generator = "order_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "order_seq_gen", sequenceName ="order_id_seq")    
    private Integer id;

    @JsonProperty("state")
    private String state;

    @JsonProperty("order_id")
    @Column(name="order_id", nullable=false, unique=true, insertable = false, 
     updatable = true, columnDefinition = "BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('order_idgen_seq')")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "order_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "order_seq_gen", sequenceName ="order_idgen_seq")
    private Integer orderId;
```

2. This is my pojo.
3. My issue with the orderId, if I call my CRUD Repository save it is creating new record with those sequence starting values,
4. while returning the object orderId is resulting null but it is there in my table.
5. I have checked with the pojo and column mapping everything is fine but  I'm not getting where it went wrong.
6. Another id sequence is returning without any issue but while coming to orderId it is resulting always null.
7. Please help me to solve this, Thankful to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think @GeneratedValue worked unless the @Id column was also present.

You could try this instead:

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Integer orderId;
```

and then make sure your Postgres column was defined as SERIAL type, which will automatically create a sequence named tablename_order_id_seq to use for it.